# Avoiding repeat code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code.

to get the `#headerfader` to resume running after the second function runs (hovering over and off again to reset the fading text)

I've duplicated the code inside the function.

Is there a more elegant way of handling this?

```
//FADER TEXT
        $('#headerFader').carousel({
            interval: 2500,
            pause: false
        });

        //BACK HOME TEXT
       $('#headerText').hover(
           function(){
               $(this).find("h1#masterHeader").animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
                   $(this).css("display", "none");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "block");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:1,});
               });
           },
           function(){
               $(this).find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
                   $(this).css("display", "none");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").css("display", "block");
                   $('#headerText').find("h1#masterHeader").animate({opacity:1,});
                   //FADER TEXT
                    $('#headerFader').carousel({
                        interval: 2500,
                        pause: false
                    });

               });
           }
       );
```

Comment: Code duplication can be avoided by moving the duplicate code into its own function and call that function instead. To learn more about functions, have a look at the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Also, you should seriously consider caching your jQuery objects into a variable.

Comment: This is code I've inherited from another developer, I'm currently attempting to fix bugs and improve the code as I go along. Cheers.

Comment: @SterlingArcher to be fair, recent versions of JQuery mitigate performance issues now by caching your selectors internally. However you still do have nanoseconds of overhead for having to make the function call in the first place, but it's definitely not the performance bottleneck it used to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a complex solution to this problem, which minimizes the numbers of `jQuery` element fetching calls**

> Note that it's clean and a lot faster than the other solutions provided. Unless it's tested I believe that this is a working piece of code.

*Since you are using `#` div id selector (which is unique) the is no need for calling `find()` function.*

```
//Object handles
var headerFader  = $('#headerFader');
var masterHeader = $('#masterHeader');
var takemeback   = $('#takemeback');

headerFader.carousel({
    interval: 2500,
    pause: false
});

//BACK HOME TEXT
headerFader.hover(
    function(){
        masterHeader.animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            takemeback.css("display", "block").animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
        });
    },
    function(){
        takemeback.animate({opacity:0}, 0, function(){
            $(this).css("display", "none");
            masterHeader.css("display", "block").animate({opacity:1}, 1000);
            headerFader.carousel({
                interval: 2500,
                pause: false
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: "Unless it's tested I believe that this is a working piece of code." Story of my life.

Comment: Force author to provide html code along with css and my WebStorm is ready to fire.  This is a very good solution + programming practice lesson. Your comment is unfair to me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I got frustrated over this one, it was already marked as solved with solution that had 3 major errors, later some guys provided some twisted solutions that forced me to fix it once and for all.

Comment: I was just joking about the way you structured your grammar, making it sound like "This code works, unless you test it." And I was saying that is the story of my life :P Your solution is fine :)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I would have provided the html / css but I'm new to MVC so I had no idea where the code was. I'll plug it in on Monday and get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Outside your other functions, you'd do this:

```
function showHeader(el) {
    $(el).css("display", "none");
    $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "block");
    $('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").animate({opacity:1,});
}
```

Then, inside your hover functions, call it:

```
showHeader(this);
```

Along with the variable suggestion above, you can chain your statements:

```
$('#headerText').find("h1#takemeback").css("display", "block").animate({opacity:1,});
```

Also, `#takemeback` should be unique, so this would do:

```
$("#takemeback").css("display", "block").animate({opacity:1,});
```

Comment: Cheers, thank you. I was also wondering about the $('#headerFader').carousel({
                        interval: 2500,
                        pause: false
                    });

Would it be worth it to stick that as it's own function too?

Comment: Purists would tell you to abstract nearly everything that can be. So, yes. :)

Comment: This is not 100% valid, you still **REPEAT** the `$(  )` and `find(  )` call.

Comment: Still not valid in his particular example.. I don't know who marked it as solve, it's miss leading.

Comment: How do you handle `"h1#masterHeader"` and `"h1#takemeback"` differentiation in `hover( inFunc, outFunc )` ?

Comment: I know who marked it as solved. That's fairly apparent. :P You're right in that there are ways to take abstraction further here, but the question wasn't that nuanced. Feel free to add all you like to your own answer and move on. +1 for the effort.